# SQL return data or filter data based on specific record number

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am trying to get SQL to pull data based on my PL number here is what I have:

```
*SELECT  [ROUTE_ID]
      ,[LINE_ID]
      ,[EVENT_ID]
      ,[DESCRIPTION]
      ,[SEQUENCE]
      ,[TYPE_CL]
      ,[CURRENT_INDICATOR_LF]
      ,[PREVIOUS_ROUTE_ID]
      ,[EFFECTIVE_FROM_DATE]
      ,[EFFECTIVE_TO_DATE]
      ,[ORIGINAL_ROUTE_ID]
      ,[PODS_USER]
      ,[CREATE_DATE]
      ,[INTERSTATE_LF]
      ,[RECORD_UPDATE_USER]
      ,[RECORD_UPDATE_DATE]
      ,[JURISDICTION_CL]
      ,[USE_CL]
      ,[PRODUCT_CL]
      ,[MXLOCATIONID]
      ,[MXFLAG_CL]
      ,[MXID]
  FROM [WBI_PODS_PROD].[dbo].[ROUTE]
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL10';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL100';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1000';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1001';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1002';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1003';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1004';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1005';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1006';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1007';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1008';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1009';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL101';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1010';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1011';
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL1012';*
```

this is just a snippet as the total I need returned is 1998 records with reach specific PL number in a specific order. however this is failing, what am I doing wrong. and can someone please produce the correct thing for me to place the PL numbers in.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't just paste your whole code in your question, but provide a minimum example that illustrates your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .
Concerning your question, remove the semicolons after your WHERE clauses.

Comment: Looks like incorrect `WHERE` syntax to me. Try `where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL10' OR MXLOCATIONID like 'PL100' OR ...`

Comment: Your semicolons at the end of the `WHERE` clauses end the statement. If you want to list it like this, you need `OR`'s in there. Better option would be to to use `IN` to match a subquery or list.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for where clause is wrong for one thing.  Should be like:

```
where MXLOCATIONID like 'PL10' or MXLOCATIONID like 'PL100' ... etc...
```

Also you are not using a wildcard (%) for like, so it is not really useful. however a better solution is to create another lookup table and put those strings in there. Something like:

```
create table location ( locationID varchar(100) );
insert into location values ('PL10');
insert into location values ('PL100');
...etc...
```

change where clause:

```
where MXLOCATIONID in ( select locationID from location) ...
```